# Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=*): Spring Batch

Tags: spring, oracle, out-of-memory, spring-batch, drools

I am facing this issue for quite sometime. Let me try to explain what exactly the problem is.
When I am running Spring batch application with large no of files with Drools I face following issue after 30-40mins of processing. The database I am having is

> oracle11g

. Please find the logs below:

```
2022-03-23 18:24:39.242 ERROR 21708 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step readProvisions in job processProvisions

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Hashtable.addEntry(Hashtable.java:435) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:476) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.getProperties(DefaultFieldSet.java:748) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
```

When I add following parameter

> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

in the run Configuration to get the memory dump I get following error:

```
2022-03-22 00:26:15.640 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 0, queue 1
2022-03-22 00:27:15.997 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 0, queue 3
2022-03-22 00:27:46.013 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 0, queue 4
2022-03-22 00:28:15.993 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 0, queue 5
2022-03-22 00:36:35.396 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-03-22 00:36:35.396 DEBUG 25460 --- [HikariPool-1 connection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:682) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
```

Now when I commented Drools functionality I was able to process 70 files in single run, quickly and without any error. I see following drools dependencies in POM.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-decisiontables -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-templates -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-templates</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-internal -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is the Configuration code:

```
@Bean
public KieSession getKieSession() {

    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/RE21DataConformRules.xls"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/RE21DataSystemRules.xls"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/CoveragesMappingRules.xls"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/AS400ARiskIDMappingForCDBRules.xls"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/HSBCoveragesTableforRE21.xls"));
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/UmbrellaILFRules.xls"));

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

    return kContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

Can any one help here to resolve this issue?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question basically "how can I get a heap dump on out of memory error"? Because right now it's talking a whole lot about drools and that's nothing to do with heap dumps and it's pulling in the wrong target audience (eg. me, a Drools person.)

Comment: No, my main focus is to solve the problem. And I am not a drools person because someone else implemented that functionality in my application. And Drools is causing the **GC over head limit exceeded** error. So a Drools person like you can also help me to solve this. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Your question isn't about that. Your question says "how do I get the memory dump". You need to update your question to indicate what you actually want to know. I can't help you get a memory dump. You also don't indicate basic things like what versions of the libraries you're using, how you're loading and calling the rules, etc.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and  comment on the updates?